# Question on Linear Transformations and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Sending each point $(x_1, x_2)$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the point $x_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$. What is the corresponding matrix?

Comment: The dimension of the required matrix is what by what?

Comment: It should be 1x2

Comment: Right, so an unknown 1x2 matrix would take what form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B}_{\mathrm{can}, \, \mathbb{R}^2} = (e_1, e_2)$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $e_1 = (1,0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1)$, and let $\mathcal{B}_{\mathrm{can}, \, \mathbb{R}} = (1)$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}$. Also, let $p_2$ be the linear mapping defined by:
$$ \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \; p_2\big( (x,y) \big) = y. $$
Then:
$$ p_2(e_1) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad p_2(e_2) = 1.$$
Therefore, the matrix of $p_2$ with respect to the pair of basis $\big( \mathcal{B}_{\mathrm{can}, \, \mathbb{R}^2}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathrm{can}, \, \mathbb{R}})$ is given by :

$$ \mathrm{Mat}\big( p_2, \mathcal{B}_{\mathrm{can}, \, \mathbb{R}^2}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathrm{can}, \mathbb{R}} \big) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 2):

$$x_2 = \begin{pmatrix}a &b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=ax_1+bx_2.$$

Now you should be able to solve on your own.